# Display photo Firebase storage with React props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I m trying to display image form my firebase storage in /spost/ Image name have same id from single spot form my "Spots" collection.

For the moment I have only 2 documents in my "spots" collection.

I don't know why, single spot for on document only show 1 image on the same img src but the path is ok. Do you have any ideas ?

My first component : IndexBanner.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore'
import { db } from '../firebase/firebase'
import { FaMapMarkerAlt } from 'react-icons/fa'
import { ImageForHomeSpot } from './ImageForHomeSpot'

export default function IndexBanner() {
    const [spots, setSpots] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        getSpots()
    }, [])


  function getSpots() {
      const spotsCollectionRef = collection(db, 'spots')
      getDocs(spotsCollectionRef).then(response => {
          const spot = response.docs.map(doc => ({
              data: doc.data(),
              id: doc.id,
              uid: doc.data().uid
          }
          ))
          setSpots(spot)
      })
          .catch(error => {
              console.log(error.message)
          })
  }

  return (
      <>
      <div className='title-section'>
          <p className='head-title-banner'>Votre prochaine photo</p>
          <h2 className='title-banner'>Les derniers lieux ajoutés</h2>
      </div>
      <div className="section-post-home">
              {spots.map((spot, index) =>
                index < 11 && (spot.data.published) && (
                    <div key={spot.id} className="grid-banner hover-scale-card">
                            <ImageForHomeSpot photoURL={spot.uid} />
                            <div className="link-card">
                                <a href={`/spots/${spot.id}`} className='spot-nom-two' > {spot.data.inputs.name}</a>
                                <a className='link-dep' href={`/departement/${spot.data.inputs.departementLower}`}><FaMapMarkerAlt /> {spot.data.inputs.departement}</a>
                            </div>
                    </div>
            ))}

       </div>
       </>
  )
}
```

My child component ImageForHomeSpot.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { getStorage, ref, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";

export function ImageForHomeSpot(photoURL) {
    
    console.log(photoURL.photoURL)
  
    const storage = getStorage();
    const prePath = "spots" + '/' + photoURL.photoURL + ".jpg";
    const storageRef = ref(storage, prePath);
    
    getDownloadURL(storageRef)
    .then((url) => {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.responseType = 'blob';
      xhr.onload = (event) => {
        const blob = xhr.response;
        
      };
      xhr.open('GET', url);
      
  
      // Or inserted into an <img> element
      const img = document.getElementById('myimg');
      img.setAttribute('src', url);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
  
    });

       
    
    return ( 
        <a href={`/spots/`}><img id="myimg" className="home-gallery-img" /></a>   
        )
}
```

Comment: Try to pass id from IndexBanner to ImageForHomeSpot. In ImageForHomeSpot you are using same id for image, so it's necessary to use different id. Use index position from spots to concatenate id each ImageForHomeSpot component

Comment: @AdrianNaranjo hey. I found a solution what do you think about it ?

Comment: Yes, if you use state for fetching image and add it to imp by url. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution to put it in a useEffect and add a state for url

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { getStorage, ref, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";


function ImageForHomeSpot(photoURL) {
    const [url, setUrl] = useState('')
        useEffect(() => {
    
        console.log(photoURL.photoURL)
  
        const storage = getStorage();
        const prePath = "spots" + '/' + photoURL.photoURL + ".jpg";
        const storageRef = ref(storage, prePath);
    
        getDownloadURL(storageRef)
            .then((url) => {
                const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.responseType = 'blob';
                xhr.onload = (event) => {
                    const blob = xhr.response;
        
                };
                xhr.open('GET', url);
      
  
                // Or inserted into an <img> element
                setUrl(url)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
  
            });

    }, [photoURL.photoURL])

    
    return ( 
        <a href={`/spots/${photoURL.photoURL}`}><img src={url} className="home-gallery-img" /></a>   
        )
}

export default ImageForHomeSpot
```

Comment: If you want to refactor something, you could change "function ImageForHomeSpot(photoURL) " by this "function ImageForHomeSpot({photoURL})" destructuring object photoUrl to use property photoURL and get shorter variable, from photoURL.photoURL to photoURL